# Тире по месту глагола

Tags: сказуемые, деепричастный-оборот

*Поэзия Катенина, вызывая оживленные нападки в 15-м и 20-х годах, к 30-м годам — мертвое явление.*

(Ю. Н. Тынянов. «Пушкин в мировой литературе». Сб. статей. Л., ГИЗ, 1926)

Фраза вызывает много вопросов и, какой основной, не определю. На поверхности: возможна ли замена (пропуск) сказуемого в данной конструкции?

Answer (score 2):

Грамматически здесь возможны два варианта:

(1) *Поэзия Катенина, **вызвавшая** оживленные нападки в 15-м и в 20-х годах, к 30-м годам — **уже мертвое явление***.

(2) *Поэзия Катенина, **вызвав** оживленные нападки в 15-м и 20-х годах, **к 30-м годам становится мертвым явлением.***

Пояснение

В заданном предложении **некорректное** использование деепричастного оборота при отсутствии сказуемого, выраженного полнозначным глаголом. Тире  стоит между подлежащим и сказуемым, связка пропущена: Поэзия — мертвое явление.

**В первом варианте** наречие "уже" добавлено для более удобного прочтения (для равновесия по объему двух частей предложения). Подлежащее имеет несколько определений, в том числе причастный оборот. Грамматика получается нормальная, но стилистически (по своей структуре) некорректная: такое предложение сложно прочесть.

Поэтому более приемлемым будет **второй вариант**.

Comment: Ответ исправлен. В первом предложении (как и в заданном варианте) тире стоит между подлежащим и сказуемым: Поэзия — мертвое явление.